# 1970s (?) JLA story with Superman frozen

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman, justice-league

I'm looking for a comic, probably published in the 1970s, where the Justice League of America was captured by a group of villains and Superman was frozen solid. Villains included Gorilla Grodd, Chronos, and probably others from the Legion of Doom. I think Brainiac was responsible for freezing Superman. One panel I clearly remember has Green Arrow using Elongated Man as a bow to shoot Red Tornado into the villains.

It might be an issue of *Justice League of America* (although I have a vague idea not) or it could be *Action Comics* or *Secret Society of Super Villains* or something more obscure, even.

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_of_America_Vol_1_218 has Elongated man being used as a bow by Green Arrow to fire Red Tornado, but no frozen superman as far as I can recall

Answer (score 14):

This is [*Action Comics #443*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_443).

- Published in 1975, the story has various baddies (including Grodd, Chronos and Brainiac) plotting against the Justice League of America.
  [image]
- Superman gets frozen.
  [image]
- Elongated man gets used as a bow to fire Red Tornado.
  [image]

Comment: Who is the red-haired woman in the first panel, who is sitting in the chair to the left, and looks like is holding a wand?

Comment: @PeterM - That's [Zazzala](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Zazzala_(New_Earth)) AKA The Queen Bee, leader of the Anti-Justice League. They get their arses kicked a few times and mostly go freelance after that.